# CSS/SVG clip path not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, clip

I am trying to use an svg as a background image using clip path, so I can change the background colour dynamically.

This is a checkbox, where the tick would be the svg.

I was using the css mask attribute using a base64 image, but this wasn't cross browser compatible. This doesn't seem to working in Firefox

I have the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/pooshonk/pen/JRxZbv) which shows my code. I will explain below.

SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" height="0px" width="0px" id="Check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
     <clipPath id="checkBox">
          <path d="M8.294,16.998c-0.435,0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553L3.61,11.724c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486,0.27-1.951
c0.615-0.467,1.488-0.344,1.953,0.27l2.351,3.104l5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652,1.267-0.852,1.921-0.445
c0.653,0.406,0.854,1.266,0.446,1.92L9.478,16.34c-0.242,0.391-0.661,0.635-1.12,0.656C8.336,16.998,8.316,16.998,8.294,16.998z" />
     </clipPath>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
div.svgCheckDiv {
    clip-path: url('#checkBox');
}
```

This works fine in codepen, but this doesn't seem to work in my application. The screenshot below shows that the image cannot be found. In my HTML I have added the svg into the body inside a hidden div.

[image]

Can anyone provide some assistance as to why this isn't loading?

I can provide more code examples and information if needed. Thanks.

**EDIT - FULL HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.svgCheckDiv {
            -webkit-mask: url('#checkBox');
            mask: url('#checkBox');
            clip-path: url('#checkBox');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="tileset vertical">
    <div class="svg_holder">
    <svg version="1.1" height="20px" width="20px" id="Check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
     <clipPath id="checkBox">
          <path d="M8.294,16.998c-0.435,0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553L3.61,11.724c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486,0.27-1.951
c0.615-0.467,1.488-0.344,1.953,0.27l2.351,3.104l5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652,1.267-0.852,1.921-0.445
c0.653,0.406,0.854,1.266,0.446,1.92L9.478,16.34c-0.242,0.391-0.661,0.635-1.12,0.656C8.336,16.998,8.316,16.998,8.294,16.998z" />
     </clipPath>
    </svg>
    </div>
   <table style="width: 100%; border:none;" align="left">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="checkbox_td" style="padding: 2px 0px 6px 0px;width:27px;">
            <input class="canvas-checkbox-selected" name="Checkbox Group" style="box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);-moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);border:2px solid #809191;background: #52acaf;float: left; width: 27px; height: 27px" type="checkbox">
            <div class="svgCheckDiv" style="background:#ff0000;height:27px;width:27px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="checkbox_label" style="padding: 2px 8px 6px 6px; height: 18px; line-height: 18px; font-size: 18px; text-decoration: none;">Item One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="checkbox_td" style="padding: 2px 0px 6px 0px;width:27px;">
            <input class="canvas-checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" style="box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);-moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);border:2px solid #809191;background: #FFFFFF;float: left; width: 27px; height: 27px" type="checkbox">
            <div class="svgCheckDiv-hidden" style="background:#ff0000;height:27px;width:27px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="checkbox_label" style="padding: 2px 8px 6px 6px; height: 18px; line-height: 18px; font-size: 18px; text-decoration: none;">uhjgjghj</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? Why try to clip a `<div>` with an SVG clipPath? Why not just use an SVG?  And what is the purpose of the mask SVGs?  Your arrangement seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: In your real environment is your CSS a separate file? If so that CSS file doesn't have an element with an id of checkBox in it (that's in your SVG file). **#id is local to a file** although that will change in future releases.

Comment: @RobertLongson - it seems you have cracked it. The css was in a seperate file and since I moved it into the head of the html it has worked. Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - were are creating a form builder that the user can change the colour of the checkbox on the fly. So there will be a checkbox, and a div overlayed on top with an svg that the user can change the colour of if need be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently a URL that starts with # points into the same file. I.e. if you write #xxx in a CSS file you'd need to have an element with an id of xxx in that CSS file itself.

The relevant specifications have changed recently and I think Firefox will change at some point to assume that #xxx would refer to a resource in the parent document.

In the meantime you can either put the CSS in the file it references or prepend the file path to the #

Answer (score 1):

You can try entering the url [about:config](http://about:config) in firefox and set the key `layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled` to `true`. That may solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no it doesn't. Even if it did, it would't work going forward as some users may not have this enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Don't put svg in **display:none** div. Because of then svg property will not execute.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <!-- SVG will not work in this div-->
</div>

<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <!-- SVG will work on this div -->
</div>
```

```css
div.svgCheckDiv {
  clip-path: url('#checkBox');
}
```

```html
<div class="svgCheckDiv" style="height: 20px;width: 20px;background: red;"></div>

<svg version="1.1" height="0px" width="0px" id="Check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
  <clipPath id="checkBox">
<path d="M8.294,16.998c-0.435,0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553L3.61,11.724c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486,0.27-1.951
 c0.615-0.467,1.488-0.344,1.953,0.27l2.351,3.104l5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652,1.267-0.852,1.921-0.445
 c0.653,0.406,0.854,1.266,0.446,1.92L9.478,16.34c-0.242,0.391-0.661,0.635-1.12,0.656C8.336,16.998,8.316,16.998,8.294,16.998z"/>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

I think you are missing this part in svg. Please put in your svg. After that this will work.

```
<clipPath id="checkBox">
    <path d="M8.294,16.998c-0.435,0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553L3.61,11.724c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486,0.27-1.951
        c0.615-0.467,1.488-0.344,1.953,0.27l2.351,3.104l5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652,1.267-0.852,1.921-0.445
        c0.653,0.406,0.854,1.266,0.446,1.92L9.478,16.34c-0.242,0.391-0.661,0.635-1.12,0.656C8.336,16.998,8.316,16.998,8.294,16.998z"/>
     </clipPath>
```

Comment: Apologies the code was there i just didn't format it correctly. Question has been edited to reflect my codepen

Comment: Don't put your svg code into hidden div. I hope will work this @Pooshonk

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work. It seems the issue is with Firefox not finding the image itself in my html. It keeps showing in the console that the image could not be loaded.

Comment: Could you upload whole html with css and svg? Then I can solve your Firefox issue @Pooshonk

Comment: I have added my html

Comment: Thanks @Pooshonk , I have added new answer with your html so please check my another answer with your html and some modification by me and now this is working fine on every modern browser and also there not any issue in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

I have little bit changes in your html and add some css property like prefix for cross browser compatibility. There is not any issue is FireFox its working fine so check this snippet into your browser.

```css
    .table{
      border: none;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .table tr td label{
      display: block;
      height: 35px;
      line-height: 30px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .table tr td label:hover{
      background: #f9f9f9;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .canvas-checkbox{
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    div.svgCheckDiv { 
      background:#ff0000;
      height:27px;
      width:27px;
      display: none;
      /*call svg by id*/      
      -webkit-clip-path: url('#checkBox'); /*For Chrome and Safari*/ 
      -moz-clip-path: url('#checkBox'); /*for Firefox*/
      -ms-clip-path: url('#checkBox'); /*for IE*/
      -o-clip-path: url('#checkBox'); /*for Opera*/
      clip-path: url('#checkBox'); 
    }
    .canvas-checkbox:checked ~  div.svgCheckDiv{
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="27">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="canvas-checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" type="checkbox" id="check1" checked>
        <div class="svgCheckDiv"></div>
      </td>
      <td><label for="check1">Item 1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="canvas-checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" type="checkbox" id="check2">
        <div class="svgCheckDiv"></div>
      </td>
      <td><label for="check2">Item 2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="canvas-checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" type="checkbox" id="check3">
        <div class="svgCheckDiv"></div>
      </td>
      <td><label for="check3">Item 3</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="svg_holder">
  <svg version="1.1" height="20px" width="20px" id="Check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
    <clipPath id="checkBox">
      <path d="M8.294,16.998c-0.435,0-0.847-0.203-1.111-0.553L3.61,11.724c-0.465-0.613-0.344-1.486,0.27-1.951 c0.615-0.467,1.488-0.344,1.953,0.27l2.351,3.104l5.911-9.492c0.407-0.652,1.267-0.852,1.921-0.445 c0.653,0.406,0.854,1.266,0.446,1.92L9.478,16.34c-0.242,0.391-0.661,0.635-1.12,0.656C8.336,16.998,8.316,16.998,8.294,16.998z" />
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as -moz-clip-path and there never has been. I suspect most of the other prefixes do nothing either.

Comment: Ok, The main thing your code is working now or not? Have you got idea from my code. @Pooshonk

Comment: It is but not because of this answer. @RobertLongson put a comment on my question with the right answer

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson for well suggest :)